# replace calendar dateto/from with year,month,day dropdown menus in ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services

best way to do this would be to have parameters which link the day dropdown column to the month one so that there are correct days in every month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would also need to use your Year parameter for a leap day in February.

I would use a table of dates based on your other parameters:

```
DECLARE @YEAR AS INT = 2016 --FOR DEV/TESTING - REFERENCE PARAMETERS
DECLARE @MONTH AS INT = 2 --FOR DEV/TESTING



DECLARE @START_DATE DATE = CAST(@YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '-' + '01'
DECLARE @END_DATE  DATE  = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @START_DATE))


;WITH GETDATES AS  
    (  
        SELECT @START_DATE AS THEDATE
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1, THEDATE) FROM GETDATES  
        WHERE THEDATE < @END_DATE  
)

SELECT DAY(GETDATES.THEDATE) AS DAYS FROM GETDATES 
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```